# Why do exceptions always incur overhead in non-leaf functions with destructible stack objects?

Tags: c++, exception

I came across the claim in the title here:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html

via here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/container/exception_handling.html

> - Exception handling violates the don't-pay-for-what-you-don't-use design of C++, as it incurs overhead in any non-leaf function that has
>     destructable stack objects regardless of whether they use exception
>     handling.

What is this referring to?

I take this bullet point to mean that any strategy for properly unwinding the stack in the event of an exception requires non-leaf functions to store some sort of information about destructible objects they placed on the stack. If that's correct, then my specific questions are:

What is this information that must be stored?

Why is it not possible to correctly unwind the stack given only an instruction address at which a throw occurred and tables of address ranges computed before run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern exception handling is indeed table based and zero cost. Unfortunately it was not the case for [Windows x86](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/20/10403718.aspx) - one of the most popular targets for game development. Most likely it was due to binary compatibility reasons but even Raymond Chen doesn't now the reason. In x64 they [implemented](https://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=469) it the way should be from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You pay in binary size.

All the code that deals with exceptions needs to be there no matter if you use exceptions or not, since in general a compiler can not know if a function can throw or not, unless it is marked `noexcept` (`noexcept` exists mostly for this reason).

The increased binary size might also hurt actual runtime performance if the code that contains the exception handling enters the CPU cache, wasting cache memory. A good compiler should be able to avoid this problem by storing all the code that performs the exception handling as far as possible from the "hot" runtime path.

Moreover, some ABI (SJLJ) implements exceptions with some runtime overhead even in the non exceptional path. Itanium and windows ABI both have zero overhead on the non-exceptional paths (and hence on these ABI you can expect exceptions to be faster than return-error-code error handling).

[This llvm doc](http://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html#overview) is a good starting point if you are interested in the differences between exception handling in the various ABIs.

Comment: I suspect there's more to the quote than that. The quote is specific to "overhead in any non-leaf function" rather than overhead in the program as a whole.

Comment: @praxeolitic It might be, but keep in mind that the code that does the exception cleanup in a function is still part of that function. Also IIRC earlier implementations were not zero overhead, and both your references are from 2007, things might have changed.